# Swiftmailer unit/functional test in symfony4.2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, swiftmailer, phpunit

Following is the code in tests/controller folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;
use App\Controller\RegisterController;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Swift_Message;

class EvaplyTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface|MockObject */
    protected $logger;
    /** @var RegisterController **/
    protected $controller;
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->logger = $this->createMock(LoggerInterface::class);
    $this->controller = new RegisterController(
        $this->logger
    );
    parent::setUp();
}

/**
 * Test for determing wether evaply id generated sucessfully or not
 */
public function testMailsent()
  {
    $message = (new Swift_Message("Successfully Registered"));
  }
}
```

I am getting this error "This test did not perform any assertions"

I just wanted to confirm that mail send successfully or not.

Comment: Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/testing.html :)

Answer (score 0):

When working with phpunit, any test has to contain an assertion. An assertion is an affirmation that needs to be verified.

For example in the Symfony doc for email testing, you'll find

> $this->assertSame(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

which means that the affirmation that the value of first parameter has to be the Same than the value of the second parameter. If this is true, the test continues / is a success. If not, php unit will report an error.

As titili said, sending an email is already documented here https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/testing.html